# How to ignore mock package when building go project?

Tags: go

As you know _test.go are ignored when go projects is build and mock package is only imported by _test.go files so if these files are not include in builded project why to simply include the mock package.
So was wondering how to ignore the files inside it when building project.

Tried adding suffix _test.go to the files in mock package but got but an error "MockStruct not declared by package mock" when used.

Also tried to use build constraints

```
//go:build ignore
```

Got same error "MockStruct not declared by package mock"

Am i missing something here?
Is using build constraints the only way?

Comment: Why would you like to ignore that fiele in the first place given it's code is needed?

Comment: @Volker As you know _test.go are ignored when go projects is build right and mock package is only imported by _test.go files so if these files are not include in builded project why to included the mock package

Comment: If a file is only used during `go test` then name it `foo_test.go` and you are done. If this leads to problems you are doing something wrong. Note that "encountered error" is not a suitable problem description.

Comment: @user17090811 What exactly is your concern? Is your `mock` package imported by your `main` package? If not, it won't be included in the resulting binary.

Comment: @jub0bs to understand this properly if a package is only imported by _test.go files it wont be included in binary but if i had used in files not having suffix _test.go then it will be included in binary right?

Comment: @user17090811 Correct, but bear in mind that a project may produce multiple binaries. If `cmd/foo/main.go` depends on your `mock` package but you're actually building `cmd/bar/main.go`, which doesn't depends on `mock`, then the resulting binary won't include anything related to `mock`.

Comment: Thanks @jub0bs just wanted this understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your mock is being used only on test files it is not imported when building the project. Go compiler does not include tests and its dependencies when building.

Try this as an example:

- Build the following code;
- Check its binary size;
- Remove the `sample_test.go` file;
- Build again and check its binary size;

Size before and after tests should not be different, and it proves that nothing from test is included in the build.

**sample.go**

```
package main

import "fmt"

type SampleInterface interface {
    DoSomething()
}

type Sample struct {
    Name string
}

func main() {
    s := Sample{}
    CallDoSomething(&s)
}

func (s *Sample) DoSomething() {
    fmt.Println("Do Something implementation ", s.Name)
}

func CallDoSomething(si SampleInterface) {
    si.DoSomething()
}
```

**sample_test.go**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "testing"
)

type sample_mock struct {
    Name string
}

func (s *sample_mock) DoSomething() {
    fmt.Println("Do Something implementation", s.Name)
}

func TestCallDoSomething(t *testing.T) {
    s := sample_mock{
        Name: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
    }
    CallDoSomething(&s)
}
```