# How to ignore gotvm when building ARM64 binary

Tags: linux, go, arm, x86-64, cross-compiling

I want to build my Go repo such that it ignores `myrepo/gotvm/*` when `GOARCH=arm64` and builds the full repo in any other case.

The project folder structure is as follows:

```
└── myrepo
    ├── go.mod
    ├── main.go
    ├── gotvm
    │   ├── array.go
    │   ├── device.go
    │   └── gotvm.go
    └── otherstuff
        └── otherstuff.go
```

When building on AMD64 everything works fine: 
`GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -o amdbuild main.go`

Building on ARM64 
`GOOS=linux GOARCH=arm64 go build -o armbuild main.go` 
gives the following error before not creating the binary:

```
package command-line-arguments
    imports github.com/myrepo/gotvm: build constraints exclude all Go files in /HOMEDIR/myrepo/gotvm
```

This is also the case when I add the following lines to the top of each file with `package gotvm` (`array.go`, `device.go`, `gotvm.go`):

```
//go:build amd64
// +build amd64`
```

Other steps I have tried:

- `go clean -modcache`
- Adding the following build flags (seperately) above all files which are part of the `package gotvm`

```
// go:build (darwin && cgo) || (linux && cgo)
//go:build amd64
// +build amd64`
```

There's a similar question on here: ([Mock packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71656403/how-to-ignore-mock-package-when-building-go-project))
, but this ignores the entire folder. I want to ignore the folder conditional on `ARCH` not being `arm64`.

**TL;DR;** Is there any way to cross-compile my repo to both ARM64 and AMD64? I want to ignore TVM for my ARM64 build.

Specs:

- Go version: `go1.20.4 linux/amd64`
- System: Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a go file with only the package clause into the `gotvm` folder could workaround the issue. For example, a `doc.go` file:

```golang
// This file is a workaround for the following issue when built with GOARCH=arm64:
//
//   build constraints exclude all Go files in /HOMEDIR/myrepo/gotvm

package gotvm
```

But when you encounter this issue, most of the time, it means that there is at least one file importing this package and this file is not excluded for `GOARCH=arm64`. Maybe you should remove the import from this file instead (or exclude this file too for `GOARCH=arm64`).

I will add a demo to illustrate the issue. These are the files:

```
├── go.mod
├── gotvm
│   └── gotvm.go
└── main.go
```

**go.mod**:

```
module example.com/m

go 1.20
```

**gotvm/gotvm.go**:

```golang
//go:build amd64

package gotvm

import "fmt"

func F() {
    fmt.Println("do awesome things using amd64")
}
```

**main.go**:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    _ "example.com/m/gotvm"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello world!")
}
```

For this demo, either remove `_ "example.com/m/gotvm"` from `main.go` or add a `doc.go` file mentioned before will fix the issue. In my opinion, it's better to remove `_ "example.com/m/gotvm"` from `main.go`.